# Ionic 2 RC: Custom decorators for components / pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-template

I want to enable ChangeDetection.OnPush for all my Pages and Components. Therefore, I wrote a function that serves as a decorator:

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';

export function PushComponent(options: any = {}) {
  options.changeDetection = ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush;
  return function(target) {
    return Component(options)(target);
  }
}
```

using it like this worked fine before the ionic 2 RC:

```
@PushComponent({
  templateUrl: 'URL'
})
export class FooBar {
  // ...
}
```

However, since the introduction of relative template URLs in ionic 2 RC, this does not work anymore ("Failed to load login.html(…)"), and I have no idea how to fix this. If I replace @PushComponent with @Component, everything works fine, so there is no mistake in the template url. Do you have any idea how to fix this, or alternatively, how to enable absolute template urls again?